# wxPython produces no GUI output

Tags: python, wxpython

Am new to GUI with wxPython.Was trying out this block of code from a book and it produces the following output but no GUI with the message string.Here's the code..

[Here's the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RP2Ox.png)

[And Here's the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJSIE.png)

Answer (score 1):

Python is case-sensitive and you need to use an uppercase 'O' in `OnInit`.

```
import wx

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        wx.MessageBox('Hello Brian', 'wxApp')
        return True

app = MyApp()
app.MainLoop()
```